# Increasing height of one div to reduce the height of other div?

Tags: angular

I'm using https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-resizable-element/demo/ in order to make my bottom element resizable only on my top border. Above i have a table which i made also resizable but only the bottom border. The issue is i want the tables bottom border to reduce or its height reduces from the bottom side when i increase the height of the element which is below. I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

This is my first post on stackoverflow sorry if i did something wrong or if i missed something.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k2beg1

I've tried using ElementRef, [style.height] and the events provided by the plugin above.

```
<div 
mwlResizable 
#tableHeight 
[style.height.px]="tableHeight" 
[ngStyle]="styleTable" 
[resizeEdges]="{bottom: true, right: false, top: false, left: false}"
style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: red">

</div>


<div 
[resizeCursorPrecision]="5" 
mwlResizable 
[validateResize]="validate"
[ngStyle]="style" 
[enableGhostResize]="true" 
[resizeEdges]="{bottom: false, right: false, top: true, left: false}" (resizing)="resizing($event)" 
style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: blue; margin-top: 30px;"
(resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)">

</div>

style: object = {};
styleTable: object = {};
tableHeight: any;

validate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
   return true;
 }

onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
   this.style = {
     position: 'fixed',
     left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
     width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
     top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
     height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
   };
 }

resizing(event) {
   this.styleTable = {
     left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
     width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
     top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
     height: `${event.rectangle.height--}px`
   }
 }
```

Comment: try creating [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example so people can better see what did you already try

Comment: I've added a stackblitz, thank you.

Comment: just some tip about formatting as this is your first question its important to have good code formatting so its readable to people that can help you corect indentation spliting attributes in seperate lines and stuf like that check history of edits of your question you will see what i have on my mind

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybohgr you need to have some max height from which you substract height of second box there are still some bugs there so you will have to fix them alone

Comment: Thank you! I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

> Hello.component.ts

```
/* tslint:disable:max-inline-declarations */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';

@Component({
  selector: 'mwl-demo',
  styles: [
    `
      .rectangle {
        position: relative;
        top: 200px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #fd4140;
        border: solid 1px #121621;
        color: #121621;
        margin: auto;
      }
      .resize-handle-top,
      .resize-handle-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        height: 5px;
        cursor: row-resize;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .resize-handle-top {
        top: 0;
      }
      .resize-handle-bottom {
        bottom: 0;
      }
      .resize-handle-left,
      .resize-handle-right {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: col-resize;
        width: 5px;
      }
      .resize-handle-left {
        left: 0;
      }
      .resize-handle-right {
        right: 0;
      }
    `
  ],
  template: `
    <div class="text-center">
      <div
        class="rectangle"
        [ngStyle]="style"
        mwlResizable
        [validateResize]="validate"
        [enableGhostResize]="true"
        [resizeSnapGrid]="{ left: 50, right: 50 }"
        (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
      >
        <div
          class="resize-handle-top"
          mwlResizeHandle
          [resizeEdges]="{ top: true }"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="resize-handle-left"
          mwlResizeHandle
          [resizeEdges]="{ left: true }"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="resize-handle-right"
          mwlResizeHandle
          [resizeEdges]="{ right: true }"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="resize-handle-bottom"
          mwlResizeHandle
          [resizeEdges]="{ bottom: true }"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent {
  public style: object = {};

  validate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
    const MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX: number = 50;
    if (
      event.rectangle.width &&
      event.rectangle.height &&
      (event.rectangle.width < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX ||
        event.rectangle.height < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX)
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
    this.style = {
      position: 'fixed',
      left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
      top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
      width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
      height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt help with the issue. Xesenix solved the issue on my post in the comments above. But thank you!